# Can’t copy files into the samba share on iPad’s default files app. But can export videos form iMovie to smb server! Error didn’t came!

Tags: ipad, sharing, smb, ipados

I set up a samba share on Linux Fedora computer. And I connected to that SMB share on my iPad but when I try to copy files into that share from my iPad I couldn’t. It shows me a error (The operation couldn’t be completed.)But when I export a video from iMovie to the smb server that error didn’t came. But when I try to do it on a another application it won’t work! The error comes again. [image]

Can anyone have solutions for this problem?

Comment: Can you share the SMB server log?

Comment: Can you try the solution proposed in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/424681/the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-operation-canceled-error-message-when-sa ?

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer gives me what I want. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/424681/the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-operation-canceled-error-message-when-sa

Comment: I will post an answer on how to do it step by step.